# endianess test and type casting

Tags: c++, c, endianness

I've known that to test the endianness, I can do following:

```
bool IsLittleEndian(){

   int a = 1;

   char* ptr = (char*)&a;

   return *ptr;
}
```

My question is why we can't just cast `int` to `char` instead of `int*` to `char*` above, like this.

```
int a = 1;

char c = (char)a;
```

Is this also OK? Otherwise, what's the reason we can't do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does this code check for endianess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572371/does-this-code-check-for-endianess)

Answer (score 9):

Both `int` and `char` are numeric types. Since the compiler knows the architecture in use, 1 in the `int` will become 1 in the `char` regardless of endianness. We use the pointer to fool the compiler into not manipulating the data.

Answer (score 0):

A cast in C is an operation that tries to represent the original value as good as possible in the new type (with some exceptions).

It does not take the bit-pattern and reinterprets it in the new type, e.g. 
`(int)3.14` shall result in `3` which has a completely different bit-pattern (probably).

Therefore `(char)(int)1` is always `1`.